# Pass array to function parameter in terminal inside for loop

Tags: command-line, bash

I have the following code:

```
myfunc(){
    group=("$1")

    for i in "${group[@]}"
        do
            printf "%s\n" "$i"
        done
}
```

I am using it to print every item in the `group` array. This array should be a parameter in the terminal. But when I try to use it in the terminal inside the `.bash_profile` file it doesnt work. I am trying this by running the following command:

```
myfunc ("one" "two" "three")
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be expecting the shell to generate some kind of anonymous array variable - AFAIK that's not possible in `bash`.

The simple approach is to pass individual arguments (which may contain whitespace, if properly quoted) and then refer to them with `"$@"`

```
myfunc ()
{
    group=("$@");
    for i in "${group[@]}"
    do
        printf "%s\n" "$i"
    done
}
```

then for example

```
$ myfunc "one nine" "two" "three four five"
one nine
two
three four five
```

although in this particular case I don't see any benefit of the additional array variable - you may as well just loop over `"$@"` directly:

```
myfunc ()
{
    for i in "$@"
    do
        printf "%s\n" "$i"
    done
}
```

---

If you just want it to "look like an array" in the calling context, then the only way I can think to do that would be to pass it as a *string* e.g. `myfunc '("one nine" "two" "three four five")'` and then `eval` the assignment inside your function `eval group="$1"` but I do **not** recommend doing that.